# Can Sanyasis be rulers according to scriptures?

Tags: scripture, kshatriya, sanyasi, kings, governance

These days, many Sanyasis have entered politics. The most notable example would be perhaps Yogi Adityanath, the chief-minister of the largest state in India, Uttar-Pradesh. However, many spiritual authorities such as highly respected Swami Vivekananda is said to have been critical of Sanyasis who indulge in politics.

My question is:

Do any scriptures allow Sanyasis to be rulers?

Comment: if someone with neither education, courage nor compassion can become minister (like it's happening these days), then someone with education, courage and compassion can also become minister. if kshatriyas don't do their duty in society, or if there are no kshatriyas, brahamanas had to step in (e.g. case of king Vena in Bhagavata Purana, at least to get a new king)

Comment: My understanding he is not sannyas, he is a brahmin. And no, scripture does not allow.

Comment: If we replace Sanyasi with celibate saints, or brahmana etc.. the answer is yes.. The taking of vow of sanyasa involves detaching from every thing material, I don't know if Yogi Adityanath or Swami paripoornanda have officially taken Sanyas. For sanyasi, it would be appropriate to inspire non-sanyasi disciples to enter such fields rather than directly entering himself. My opinion is even if they are sanyasis, we can't blame them for choosing politics if they saw no alternative and entered for greater benefit of society.

Comment: He is a yogi from nath panth and not typical sanyasi. Nath panth and akharas are known to contribute to nationalism and even they fight with invaders when needed.

Comment: There is nothing bigger than rashtra dharma. When national structure of dharma is in danger then everyone should contribute to the need of the hour

Comment: Not related to your question but on a side note Rajasthan is the largest state of India in terms of area while UP is largest in terms of population.

Comment: well said @RakeshJoshi, yogi adityanath is like an oasis in desert of politics.

Comment: Another such person is Swami Paripurnananda who is active in telangana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to scriptures --- **No way**.. It is evident even from common sense ..

First of all, one who has renounced should not live in his native place. After he has renounced he has to start living in another place. How is that possible for a king?

> **A sage should leave his native land right after he has renounced. He should live far away from his own**, like a thief just released from
>   jail (Maitreni Upanishad 115)

Secondly, he has to be on the move always, he is not allowed to stay in a particular place for around 8 months of a year. Only during the rainy season he is allowed stay in a particular place. Obviously such a lifestyle can't be followed by a king.

> An ascetic shall wander alone for eight months;" says the Aruni (8),
>   "he shall keep a fixed residence during the entire rainy season or
>   during just two months of it."

Thirdly, a Sannyasi has renounced everything. He can't **own** anything. Even for securing food **he has to beg**. But on the other hand, a king will own so many things. He also can't go begging for food.

The things that a Sannyasi is allowed to carry/own are very few:

> A pot, a drinking cup, a sling, a tripod, a pair of shoes, a patched
>   garment against the cold, a loincloth, a water strainer, a bathing
>   cloth, and an outer garment: an ascetic should avoid anything else
>   other than these
>
> Laghu Sannyasa (21)
>
> Let him sleep on a river bank or in a temple. Let him not afflict his
>   body with extremes of pleasure or of pain. Let him bathe, drink, and
>   cleanse himself with water that is purified. When he is praised let
>   him not rejoice, nor curse others when he is reviled.

A Sannyasi also can not have a sexual life which a king is allowed to have. Moreover, a Sannyasi can not indulge in several matters which are unavoidable for a king, for e.g law enforcement etc etc:

> "An ascetic's mind is inevitably perturbed if he behaves with women
>   foolishly in these four ways. When his mind is perturbed he will
>   perish. "Craving, anger, falsehood, deceit, greed, delusion, likes and
>   dislikes, fine arts, the work of interpretation, desire, passion,
>   possessions, [157] egotism, selfishness, the practice of medicine, law
>   enforcement, atonement, travel abroad, and the use of mantras,
>   medicines, poisons, and blessings: all these are forbidden to him.
>   Practicing them will cause his downfall
>
> Narada Parivrajaka. Upanishad.