Can a Kshatriya become a priest or a monk?
I've been reading the Manusmriti because I've always heard many negative views about it but I wanted to read it myself to know what it really says. I'm reading Prof. Patrick Olivelle's translation although I hope to read the original in Sanskrit one day.
Now in the first chapter, there's a section in which Manu describes the different duties and occupations assigned to the four varnas.

"For the protection of this whole creation, that One of dazzling
brilliance assigned separate activities for those born from the mouth,
arms, thighs, and feet. To Brahmins, he assigned reciting and
teaching the Veda, offering and officiating at sacrifices, and
receiving and giving gifts. To the Ksatriya, he allotted
protecting the subjects, giving gifts, offering sacrifices, reciting
the Veda, and avoiding attachment to sensory objects; and to the
Vaisya, looking after animals, giving gifts, offering sacrifices,
reciting the Veda, trade, moneylending, and agriculture. single
activity did the Lord allot to the Sudra, however: the ungrudging
service of those very social classes (10.74-80)." - Manusmriti,
Adhyaya 1.87-91

As we can see, according to Manu, Brahmins have the right to recite and teach the Vedas as well as the right to offer and officiate at sacrifices. Thus they can of course they can be priests ("pandit") and monks ("sanyasins") which is their natural role.
But what about Kshatriyas? They have been given the right to recite the Vedas and offer sacrifices, meaning they are meant to receive some sort of a religious education but then they don't have the right to teach the Vedas (or to officiate at a sacrifice).
Now as far as I can tell, this effectively bars them from becoming a priest or a monk since priests are expected to officiate ceremonies and monks are also expected to do the same before going into monkhood (and both are expected to take disciples to pass the knowledge of their sampradaya to the next generation).
Edit: I'm at the second chapter now and there's something else I found which is quite interesting. There's a verse here which defines who is a teacher (acharya) and in this case not just an ordinary teacher but someone who teaches the Vedas.

"The twice-born man who initiates a pupil and teaches him the Veda
together with the ritual books and the secret texts* is called
'Teacher.'"- Manusmriti, Adhyaya 2.140

Notice how Manu defines an acharya as a "twice-born man who teaches the Vedas". He could've easily defined an acharya as a "Brahmin who teaches the Vedas". But instead he uses the term "twice-born" which includes not just Brahmins but also Kshatriyas. It feels like this is a contradiction with regards to Adhyaya 1.87-91 I quoted earlier.

Only Brahmins are lallowed to officiate on behalf of others so only they can become priests .. also by monks do you mean Sannyasis?

@Rickross Yeah I mean sannyasis, including the ones who belong to maths like the ones established by Adi Shankaracharya for example. Can Kshatriyas join such maths and become a sannyasin?

Ok .. I am trying to find one answer of mine where I have quoted from Upanishads regarding who all are fit to renounce but could not find the answer yet

This answer is relevant -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24136

Also see this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30074/4732 .. A Ksatriya is meant to be a ruler but Sannyasis can not be rulers according to scriptures.

While all sources unanimously state that none apart from brahmanas are entitled to be the priests for divinities (& not for sub-divine beings), how you define the term monk determines the answer. In the Mahabharata, there is a passing reference to Shantanu's unmarried elder brother becoming a monk. Sannyasa is taken by 2 sorts of people - old people at the end of their lives as per the ashrama system, after undergoing brahmacharya, grihastha & vanaprastha in successive order & others (not necessarily old) who abandon the world after brahmacharya without undergoing grihastha stage.

Not every Hindu in ancient times agreed with Manu Smriti's opinion. I have given a contrary opinion below. All four groups have equal rights according to Sage Bhrigu.

The sage Bhrigu said, ‘There is really no distinction between the
different orders. The whole world at first consisted of Brahmanas.
Created (equal) by Brahman, men have, in consequence of their acts,
become distributed into different orders. They that became fond of
indulging in desire and enjoying pleasures, possessed of the
attributes of severity and wrath, endued with courage, and unmindful
of the duties of piety and worship, - these Brahmanas possessing the
attributes of passion, - became Kshatriyas. Those Brahmanas again who,
without attending to the duties laid down for them, became possessed
of both the attributes of Goodness and Passion, and took to the
professions of cattle-rearing and agriculture, became Vaisyas. Those
Brahmanas again that became fond of untruth and injuring other
creatures, possessed of cupidity, - engaged in all kinds of acts for a
living, and fallen away from the purity of behavior, and thus wedded
to the attributes of Darkness, became Sudras. Separated by these
occupations, Brahmanas, falling away from their order, became members
of the other three orders. All the four orders, therefore, have always
the right to the performance of all pious duties and of sacrifices.
Even thus were the four orders at first created equal by Brahman who
ordained for all of them (the observances disclosed in) the words of
Brahma (in the Vedas). Through cupidity alone, many fell away, and
became possessed by ignorance. The Brahmanas are always devoted to the
scripture on Brahma; and mindful of vows and restraints, are capable
of grasping the conception of Brahma. Their penances therefore never
go for nothing. They amongst them are not Brahmanas that are incapable
of understanding that every created thing is Supreme Brahma.

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CLXXXVIII

Yeah I know. I also don't agree with the Manusmriti on this. In fact, I believe in Sri Narayana Guru's concept of Oru Jathi, Oru Matham, Oru Daivam ("One Varna, One Dharma, One Ishavara"). But I was curious to know the different positions held by different sacred texts.

@AbhishekMhatre well Manu is generally viewed as authentic also Pradip that doesn't nessecarily deny Manu please give direct scriptural sources where an authentic perosnality criticized Manu?

All orders have the right to perform holy rites does not mean all can become priests .. no scriptures allow Ksatriyas or any one other than Brahmins becoming priests ..Priests mean who officiate on behalf of others (Yajaman) in return of Dakshina .. Ksatriyas, Vaishyas etc are not allowed to do that by any scriptures.

@Haridasa Well how about Manu himeself? He contradicts himself when he says in Adhyaya 2.140 that dwija men (which includes Kshatriyas) can be teachers of the Vedas but then in Adhyaya 1.87-91 he assigns the right to teach only to Brahmins. Moreover the existence of Kshatriyas who became rishis like Vishwamitra and Janaka is again an argument against Manu's claim that Kshatriyas cannot take on the role of Brahmins.

Manu 2.140. They call that Brahmana who initiates a pupil and teaches him the Veda together with the Kalpa and the
Rahasyas, the teacher (akarya, of the latter).  -- Is this the verse you are talking about?  @AbhishekMhatre

@Rickross No, the verse actually uses the term dwjia. Here's the exact verse: upanīya tu yaḥ śiṣyaṃ vedamadhyāpayeddvijaḥ |sakalpaṃ sarahasyaṃ ca tamācāryaṃ pracakṣate. Even I was surprised when I first read this.
